# Redesigning TV Remote for a different User Interface

Tags: safety, short-circuit

The buttons of a standard TV remote are simply conductors covered by insulators (for user protection) to be pressed in order to short circuit a node in a grid of wires.

What if we want to replace this mechanical solution (of pressing down) with an electrical solution which depends on wireless commands?

Do we short circuit remotely, and if so what's a safe way to do so?

Comment: Search for "capacitive touch buttons", you will find a wide range of tutorials, descriptions, and reference material for a non-contact / non-pressure based approach for buttons, as is used on a plethora of modern electronic devices, including TV / universal remote controls.

Comment: You probably want to be a bit more specific about the end-result you're after. Not to mention the 'insulators' in TV remotes are for environmental protection, you won't get zapped too badly off a pair of AAA or similar batteries.

Comment: All remote controls I've ever seen use a couple of 1.5V batteries and these do not pose an electricity hazard - this means that the insulators over the buttons are for something else like preventing coffee spills ruining the circuit. How would wireless commands avoid "pressing down" buttons?  Are you considering using a radio transmitter to activate a TV remote control that then activates the TV and if you are, why?

Comment: @PeterJ Question edited. Any better?

Comment: @Andyaka Some sort of wireless module, and to provide a different user-interface.

Comment: The reason why they use the membrane sheet is because it is cheap and has acceptable lifetime, compared to mechanical switches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this in the past using relays as well as transistors, the former being better. This is however a horribly ugly way to do it. I would recommend recording the TV IR codes using something like the [IRToy](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/USB_Infrared_Toy). This would allow you to replay any code when required and avoids most of the interfacing problems.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, about implementing a non-pressure-based pushbutton matrix?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I think the question is asking how to interface a circuit to the existing pushbutton circuit, so they can be activated via electrical means, rather than mechanical. If OP is trying to automate some function used by the original remote, the code can be learned and played back by computer now. No need to re-purpose the original remote. Just my interpretation, though.